# Address from pubkey

Tags: anchor, web3.js, anchor-lang

I need to be able to derive an anchor.Address object from a solana/web3.js::Pubkey object based on this error I receive in editor:

````
  Type at position 2 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
    The types of 'accounts' are incompatible between these types.
      Property 'state' is missing in type '{ tokenProgram: string; stakeMint: string; userStakeTokenAccount: string; userStakeTokenAccountAuthority: string; programBeefTokenAccount: string; userBeefTokenAccount: string; beefMint: string; }' but required in type 'Accounts<{ name: "state"; isMut: true; isSigner: false; } | { name: "tokenProgram"; isMut: false; isSigner: false; } | { name: "stakeMint"; isMut: true; isSigner: false; } | { name: "userStakeTokenAccount"; isMut: true; isSigner: false; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>'.```
````